# Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays in angular

Tags: angular

when I try to update data based on the id unable to iterate data in form fields, please find the screenshots for more details

[Error Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7vUc.png)

Comment: please add your code snippets so we can see what you were trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to iterate through ngFor data must be in form of an array

html.component.html

```
<div *ngFor = "let title of fetchData">
  {{title.title}} -- {{title.description}} -- {{title.tagline}} {{title.date}}
</div>
```

html.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  fetchData = [{"title":"saurabh","description":"dd","tagline":"tt","date":"dd"},{"title":"aman","description":"dd","tagline":"tt","date":"dd"},{"title":"jessica","description":"dd","tagline":"tt","date":"dd"},{"title":"rosh","description":"dd","tagline":"tt","date":"dd"}];


}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy now issue has fixed